# What is a good linux os to have that focuses on becoming a good system admin?

Tags: linux, vmware, operating-systems, command-line-arguments

I want to build my skills and knowledge but dont know where to start. I have a vmworkstation that i want to install a linux os but dont know which one to install to eventually make me a good system admin. Any and all advice is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, Voted to close because this is opinion based.  One thought process might be to start with Ubuntu -> Debian.  Another might be Fedora -> CentOS.  Another might  be Slackware (I imagine.  Thats how I started 20 odd years ago, and from what I hear its still a boots-and-braces install).   The difficulty is to transition from a GUI to a shell interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, most distros have the same under the hood way of dealing with things, but just put different GUIs on them.  So if you learn how to do things from the command line, aka CLI, your set for most distros.  Beyond that many of the GUIs have frustrating limitations the CLI doesn't.

Therefore, just get the latest version of something a lot of people use. (See distrowatch.com for popularity trends.)

Security, is a critical part of being an admin.  Knowledge is your best defense.  You need to test your system with hacking tools like nessus and backtrack.  It will expose weakness, then you need to research and learn how to fix those.

You need to stay away from old versions and most, if not all, contain some vulnerable packages.  If it hasn't been updated at least once in 2015 don't waste your time.

Since you have VMware you should not limit yourself to 1 distro.  You need to frequent linux websites like tecmint.com,unixmen.com, linuxtoday.com, distrowatch.com, and more.

Linux has many moving parts and each one is separate area of learning.  For example, you need to know iptables and ipset for network security, but the filesystem is a separate topic.